# Create custom landing page before wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have this page called `landingpage.html` basically the landing page consist only of an image and a button before going to `index.php` (wordpress).

can I just rename the landing page to `index.html` and the wordpress `index.php` to something else? So when the link in landing page is clicked, it goes to the wordpress front page?

Comment: you can do it but need to set preferences in hosting cpanel setting, but each home page link must be link this domainname.com/index.php not link just domainname.com in wordpress home page links else it will redirect to again landingpage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually set WordPress to serve up a static page when the user comes to the site.

In order to do this, you just create a page with the title of "Home", fill it with content and publish. Next, create an empty page with the title of "Blog", "News", etc. that matches what you want it to be called. Leave it blank and publish it.

Once these to pages are published, go to *Reading* under *Settings*. There are radio buttons under **Front Page Display**. Click on *A Static Page* and then select "Home" for *Front Page* and "Blog" for *Posts Page*.

Full instructions are available at http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Comment: how can i use the default front-page.php as the Post Page